# looping through JSON, cannot read property 'length' error when using Object.keys()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON object:

```
{
"KF":
    [{"name":"NATALIA","th":10},{"name":"STEVE","th":10}],
"LC" : 
    [{"name":"RANDY","th":10},{"name":"EVAN","th":10}],
"EL":
    [{"name":"SCOTTY","th":10},{"name":"SKIP","th":10}] 
}
```

I'm trying to get the key values, loop through each one and append() the names to their corresponding div id's. The code I'm using:

```
$.getJSON("players.json", function(data){
    var clans = Object.keys(data);
        $.each(clans, function(i, clan){
            console.log(clan);
            $.each(data.clan, function(n, player){
                $('#' + clan).append(player.name+' <span class="badge">'+player.th +'</span><br>\n');
            });
        });
    });
```

I'm getting an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined, but I'm not sure why.

If I explicitly tell the data object what I want it works... for example:

```
$.each(data.EL, function(n, player){
    $('#EL').append(player.name+' <span class="badge">'+player.th +'</span><br>\n');
});
$.each(data.KF, function(n, player){
    $('#KF').append(player.name+' <span class="badge">'+player.th +'</span><br>\n');
});
$.each(data.LC, function(n, player){
    $('#LC').append(player.name+' <span class="badge">'+player.th +'</span><br>\n');
});
```

But this obviously isn't practical. Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I assumed this would be a duplicate, but when you don't know the problem it's hard to know what to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the value of `clan` when accessing `data`, you need to use the `[]` syntax because it's dynamic.

Because of this, `data.clan` is undefined.

```
$.each(data[clan], function(n, player){
//         ^^^^^^ [] notation for a dynamic key
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution I was looking for... I knew it had to be something simple.